# how to parse json into php

Tags: php

i have a json data retrieved from data base i.e

```
$result=array();
$query="SELECT * FROM fish";
$result1 = mysql_query($query, $conn);
while ($table = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   $result[]=$table;
}
   echo json_encode($result);
```

and this give me the result

```
[{"fish_id":"1","name":"first fish update","info":"this is my first fish update","image":"http:\/\/www.localhost\/cafe\/pics\/logout (1).gif"}]
```

but from another page when i call this json data i.e

```
$input = file_get_contents("http://localhost/fish/fish-json.php");
$json=json_decode($input);
echo $json->fish_id;
```

it give me the error

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/fish/json-to-php.php on line 13 Call Stack: 0.0005 318764 1. {main}() /var/www/fish/json-to-php.php:0
```

Comment: Does `$input` contain any result when you echo it?

Comment: `print_r()` or `var_dump()` is your friend :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is an array of object, so

```
echo $json[0]->fish_id;
```

To loop

```
if (!is_array($json)) die('...');
foreach ($json as $key=>$fish)
{
  echo $fish->fish_id;
}
```

Comment: hay thanks,it works but if there are more than one records then how could i iterate to this

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$input = file_get_contents("http://localhost/fish/fish-json.php");
$json=json_decode($input);
echo $json['fish_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try `echo $json['fish_id'];` i might suspect it convert it to an array

Answer (score 0):

try this first:

```
echo $json;
```

to check if you got valid json.
Eventually, the php in fish-json.php was not executed.

Answer (score 0):

By default json_decode returns an stdClass object.
You have to give a second parameter for this function TRUE.

```
$json=json_decode($input, TRUE);
echo $json[0]['fish_id'];
```